# how to connect the pins of accelerometer MMA7361

Tags: accelerometer

i have an accelerometer modulw whose pins are 5v,3.3v,x,y,z,sleep,og-detect,g select,selftest. i have connect only 5v,x,y,z please tell me how to use other pins. In my connection it gives random values.

Comment: Datasheet where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect sleep pin to vcc and gselect to grond if you want to use 1.6 g otherwise vcc if you want to use 6g. keep other pins NC